# RethinkDB - Chain multiple getAll-Functions

Tags: java, rethinkdb, chain

What is the most efficient way, to chain multiple getAll-Functions in RethinkDB? In my case, i work in java and need to do a getAll on a List. This is how it looks like:

To get all the documents from the ***test*** table, where ***name*** is in ***myListOfNames***.

```
r.table("test").getAll(r.args(myListOfNames)).optArg("index", "name").run(conn)
```

But how can i chain another getAll-Function most efficiently? For example if i also need documents with ***city*** in ***myListOfCitys***. I can't just append a getAll-Function, and using a filter won't use secondary indexes and won't be efficient enough. I could append a ***forEach***-Function and use getAll for each of the documents, but i dont think, this will be efficient enough. So my question is, what is the most efficient way, to chain multiple getAll-Functions, which are using secondary indexes?

I'm thankful for every response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use union:

```
r.table("test")
 .getAll(r.args(myListOfNames))
 .optArg("index", "name")
 .union(
   r.table("test")
     .getAll(r.args(myListOfCities))
     .optArg("index", "city"))
```